# python function that takes multiple key value pairs

Tags: python

I want to create a python function that will take multiple keyword value arguments I feed it. I have already written something but it is not working the way I want it to. It is only printing the first argument. What is the best way to create this function?

```
def hello(**kwargs):
    _path_ = "%s == %s"
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        result = _path_ % (key, value)
    print (result)

hello(name1="one", name2="two")
```

Comment: What is result supposed to be? A list of paths? Right now you are just overriding it with a new string every iteration.

Comment: `print` statement should be inside for loop.

Comment: This is a function, not a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's printing only one result because the print is outside the for loop. Therefore it only prints the last stored kwarg.

do something like this instead:

```
def hello(**kwargs):
    _path_ = "%s == %s"
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        result = _path_ % (key, value)
        print(result)

hello(name1="one", name2="two")
```

output:

```
name1 == one
name2 == two
```

Answer (score 0):

the `print` statement should be inside of for loop because its assigning one value at each time, the next value will change , also its not a `class` its a `function`:

```
def hello(**kwargs):
    _path_ = "%s == %s"
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        result = _path_ % (key, value)
        print (result)

hello(name="2", lebron="3")
```

you can also make a dict with key, value pair like this :

```
result = {}
for key, value in kwargs.items():
    result[key] = value
print (result)
```